# How to fix an error converting a time column in a dataframe with the to_datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, date, time

I am have troubles converting a date column in my dataframe to ensure its a date type.  Here is my dataframe:

```
    symbol   price    time
0   MSFT      97.71   9:39:02 AM
1   GOOG    1067.87   9:39:06 AM
2   AAPL     187.61   9:39:07 AM
3   CA        35.39   9:38:15 AM
4   SAP      110.76   9:38:13 AM
```

The thing is the time column already has AM/PM.

Here is my code:

```
dropped_col['time'] = pd.to_datetime(dropped_col.time,  format='%I:%M:%S')
```

The error that I get is:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains:  AM

Basically, I want the time field to be formatted correctly for charting and using any stat functions.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: You forgot to include the `AM` in your time format specification, as stated by the `ValueError` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
dropped_col['time'] =pd.to_datetime(dropped_col.time.time,  format='%I:%M:%S %p')
```

Refer to [docs](http://strftime.org/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me alot.